# Django unbound and bound forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am creating a service where people can create guides including decks for a video game called hearthstone. First one has to select their hero:

```
class SelectHero(ListView):
    template_name = 'hsguides/select_hero.html'
    model = Hero

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SelectHero, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['heroes'] = Hero.objects.all()
        return context
```

And when it is selected I render a template with the deck and the guide form. Now when I use this setup:

**view**

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def guide_create_view(request, hero):
    print(DeckForm)
    return render(request, 'hsguides/guide_create.html', {
        'DeckForm': DeckForm(hero),
        'GuideForm': GuideForm,
    })
```

**form**

```
class DeckForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        exclude = ('dust', 'hero',)


    def __init__(self, hero=None, **kwargs):
        super(DeckForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if hero:
            self.fields['weapon_cards'].queryset = Weapon.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                         Q(card_class=hero))
            self.fields['spell_cards'].queryset = Spell.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                       Q(card_class=hero))
            self.fields['minion_cards'].queryset = Minion.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                         Q(card_class=hero))
```

I see that this form is *unbound* and it is not valid when I want to use it in my save view

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login")
def guide_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        deck_form  =  DeckForm(request.POST)
        guide_form = GuideForm(request.POST)
        print(guide_form.is_bound) # printed value, True
        print(deck_form.is_bound) # printed value, False
        if guide_form.is_valid() and deck_form.is_valid():
            new_deck  = deck_form.save(commit=False)
            new_deck.dust = 0 #TODO create a count method for the dust field!
            new_deck.save()

            new_guide = guide_form.save(commit=False)
            new_guide.author = Account.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            new_guide.deck = Deck.objects.get(id=new_deck.id)
            new_guide.save()
        else:
            print(guide_form.errors)
            print(deck_form.errors)
    else:
        deck_form = DeckForm()
        guide_form = GuideForm()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/guides/search-guide/')
```

Now I am really dependent on this part:

```
def __init__(self, hero=None, **kwargs):
        super(DeckForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if hero:
            self.fields['weapon_cards'].queryset = Weapon.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                         Q(card_class=hero))
            self.fields['spell_cards'].queryset = Spell.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                       Q(card_class=hero))
            self.fields['minion_cards'].queryset = Minion.objects.filter(Q(card_class='neutral') |
                                                                         Q(card_class=hero))
```

But I don't know how to validate the deck form and save it in the best way. How can I approach this situation the best with regards to best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've redefined the signature of your form so that the first argument is `hero`, but then you instantiate it with just `request.POST`.

Instead of doing that, get `hero` from the kwargs, and always make sure you accept both args and kwargs.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    hero = kwargs.pop('hero', None)
    super(DeckForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if hero:
        ...
```

Remember to pass the hero argument in by keyword:

```
return render(request, 'hsguides/guide_create.html', {
    'DeckForm': DeckForm(hero=hero),
    'GuideForm': GuideForm,
})
```